# ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined for app.scss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, sass

While running my React project on an Azure pipeline, I encounter an error specifically during the 'npm build:prod' phase.

The process works seamlessly on my local environment, but on Azure, it crashes and throws a 'ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined' related to './src/App.scss'.

How can I resolve this issue and ensure a successful build on the Azure pipeline?

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.5.2",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.12",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^2.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "globalthis": "^1.0.3",
    "mark.js": "^8.11.1",
    "msal": "^1.1.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.20.0",
    "react-mark.js": "^9.0.7",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react-router-config": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "react-simple-tree-menu": "^1.1.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.6",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:test": "env-cmd -f ./.env.test npm run-script build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f ./.env.prod npm run-script build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 9",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/*index.js",
      "!src/serviceWorker.js",
      "!src/polyfill.js"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12",
    "npm": ">=6"
  }
}
```

The error occurs when the job is running the npm run build:prod. I can run npm run build:prod locally tho...